# Unified online resource / dataset where I can view the percentage of an ETF dividend that is regarded as qualified dividends by the IRS?

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm looking for an online resource / dataset where I can enter the ticker symbol of an ETF and I can see the percentage of its dividends that is regarded as qualified dividends by the IRS. Does such resource exist?

I unsuccessfully tried [Fidelity's screener](https://screener.fidelity.com/ftgw/etf/goto/snapshot/distributions.jhtml?symbols=VYM) and [seekingalpha.com](https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/VWO/dividends/scorecard). I don't want to have to dig into the ETF issuer's official website each time I'm looking for such information.

Comment: I am still interested in such a dataset.

Comment: Any pointer is welcome.